# How to grow and move div/p tags upwards based on content height

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this has been asked to death already. But I can't find a way to grow content upwards. 
You know how content behaves normally, extends downward, pushing content after down as the content above extends. Is there a way you can do this, but upwards?
Right now the code is ordered like this: 
H1 - Title: needs to adjust if it breaks into two lines 
p - Tags: needs to adjust height if it breaks to two lines and move the H1 up 
p - Text: same as tags but move both tags and title upwards
p - Number: doesn't grow much, but needs to stick to the corner
p - Button: Never grows and needs to stick to the corner

[image]

edit 1: better image, yellow arrows show which ways content need to be able to grow, red shows space between each section.
edit 2: clarified question.
edit 3: edited image to signify that all elements stick to bottom and NOT top.
edit 4: added what I'm trying to avoid to image.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS for what you tried. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `here's a visual description of what I need:` and what next ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif You know how content behaves normally, extends downward, pushing content after down as the content above extends. Is there a way you can do this, but upwards?

Comment: i advise you to read about flex and how we can align using `flex-end` also margin:auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to achieve this. Make sure the height of the container is correct and then you can align all the elements to the bottom with flexbox.  As the content grows, the container will fill upwards.

Here's another good resource on flexbox: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

--

Specifically in this example, if you set the container to be `display: flex;` with a `flex-direction: column;` then it will allow you to align the child elements vertically instead of horizontally like you do with floats.

Setting `justify-content` to `flex-end` is what aligns everything to the bottom.  That's where the magic happens.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">TITLE</h1>
        <p class="tags">Tags, Things, Stuff, More Stuff</p>
        <p class="text">Non via nia sex praemissae spectentur contingere respondeam. 
            Has scriptis usu corporis physicae. Existentia lor perspicuum sub mutationum 
            agnoscerem vis advertatur. Multo in entis ad rebus tactu oculi ad. Ii in 
            innatis viderer me hominem at ipsemet. Vitro errem im is anima famam se istas.
            Mea credendas ero persuasum sanguinem vox. Sequeretur uti aut frequenter vul 
            commendare describere. Ex superare aeternum ob connivet ac earumque co. 
            Physicae fenestra obturabo ii is se.</p>
        <div class="bottom">
            <p>Number</p>
            <p>Button</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.text, .bottom {
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-start;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bottom {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PhilipAarseth you can also simply use margin:auto like i did with my solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to position the elements at the bottom of the page. Here is my solution:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2rem;
  font: 1.6rem/1.4 Roboto, monospace;
}

#number,
#button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#number {
  left: 2rem;
}

#button {
  right: 2rem;
}

#topWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 7.24rem;
  width: calc(100% - 4rem);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 9.24rem);
  overflow: auto;
}

#text,
#tags,
h1 {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#tags,
#title {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#tags {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#title {
  background-color: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<div id="topWrapper">
  <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
  <p id="tags">Tag, Tag, Tag, Tag, Tag</p>
  <p id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<p id="number">100,000</p>
<p id="button">Button</p>
```

You can also view it in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ztbo3cuz/) fiddle. Moreover, see how it behaves if the [title is longer](https://jsfiddle.net/ztbo3cuz/1/) or if the [tag list is longer](https://jsfiddle.net/ztbo3cuz/2/). If the content becomes to much, a vertical scrollbar is added.

Comment: Thanks @tavkomann, but I don't think this would solve the issue here as if the text box barely have any text you would have awkward spaces below with fixed positioning. I added a third section to the image to clarify.

Comment: @PhilipAarseth There will not be larger spaces between the buttons and the text or between tags and the title since these spaces are hard-coded to 1rem, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4r4a3owj/) fiddle. The only space will be at the top of the page. Could you clarify what you mean?